# What's the best way to define $\mathbb{H}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, analysis, definition

I had once defined $\mathbb{C}$ as $\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}$ **as a set**, then I found it extremely uncomfortable when doing complex analysis or measure theory. So I changed its definition so that $\mathbb{R}\subset\mathbb{C}$.

Now, I just faced $\mathbb{H}$(Hamilton) and I'm hesitating to choose the definition for it.

Is it a good choice to define it as a set such that $\mathbb{C}\subset\mathbb{H}$? Or is it okay to define it as $\mathbb{R}^4$ (In this case, neither $\mathbb{R}$ nor $\mathbb{C}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{H}$)

And is $\mathbb{H}$ being used in analysis for computations?

Comment: I mean, the question becomes:  how do you plan on using this object?

Comment: @AdamHughes I have no idea where it is being used. That's why I posted this question to ask people who has experienced with this. I'm just hesitating at the page introducing $\mathbb{H}$. I want a flexible definition so that I can use it (without pain) anywhere in mathematics where it is useful.

Comment: Personally,  I've always seen it defined as an algebraic extension of $\mathbb R$,  i.e, $\mathbb R (i,j,k)$ where $i^2=j^2=k^2=ijk=-1$

Comment: I mean, that's not necessarily going to be possible. At times it's advantageous to think of $\Bbb C$ as $\Bbb R^2$ without a prejudiced inclusion of $\Bbb R$ even (which relates to your original example). As an algebra over the reals, it's often easiest to give the usual presentation with $i,j,k$, but sometimes it's better to have it as a matrix algebra, and other times it's better to just leave it as $\Bbb R^4$ plus some stuff.

Comment: @Alan So have you not seen $\mathbb{H}$ out of the field of algebra? Such as analysis? Actually I switched my major from physics to mathematics, and I remember that there were few chapters about quaternions in quantum mechanics(? I don't remember actually. I forgot physics at all)

Comment: @AdamHughes So what's your definition for $\mathbb{H}$? Is it being used in analysis so that computation between $\mathbb{H}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ occur frequently? If so, i would not hesistate to define it as a set **containing** $\mathbb{C}$, otherwise I wouldn't.

Comment: @Rubertos I use different ones depending on the context I need them in. If I'm doing things with cross products of matrices, I tend to use the matrix definition, if I'm doing things where I really want to milk the $ij=k, \ldots$ relations, I'll use the ring presentation, when I want to talk about addition, I use the $\Bbb R^4$ identification. I use them not necessarily "all the time," but frequently enough that I know that multiple points of view are advantageous. In particular:  as a professional, I'm not limited by one characterization,when there are many well-known ones around.

Comment: While $\mathbb{C}$ contains $\mathbb{R}$ in a “natural” way (there is just one embedding), the same can't be said about $\mathbb{H}$: there are infinitely many subfields of $\mathbb{H}$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. Three of them are obtained by adjoining $i$, $j$ or $k$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (which is uniquely embedded in $\mathbb{H}$). But any quaternion $q$ such that $q^2=-1$ can be used.

Comment: @Rubertos I haven't, no.   But then, I'm only in my second year of grad school.